# Property 'withComponents' does not exist on type 'typeof DynamicModule'. [Angular]

Tags: angular, dynamic, content-management-system, angular9, angular10

```
import { DynamicModule } from 'ng-dynamic-component';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { StoryblokService } from './storyblok.service';
import { StoryblokDirective } from './storyblok.directive';
import { TeaserComponent } from './teaser/teaser.component';
import { GridComponent } from './grid/grid.component';
import { PageComponent } from './page/page.component';
import { FeatureComponent } from './feature/feature.component';
 
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    PageComponent,
    StoryblokDirective,
    TeaserComponent,
    GridComponent,
    FeatureComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    DynamicModule.withComponents([
      PageComponent,
      TeaserComponent,
      GridComponent,
      FeatureComponent
    ])
  ],
```

Error with this DynamicModule.withComponents tried to download older dynamic version but no use
got this code from storyblok did all the steps

Answer (score 0):

Go to **package.json**  and change version of **ng-dynamic-component**:

**"dependencies": {
....
"ng-dynamic-component": "^5.0.0",
...
}**